# Asp.net mvc3 runtime errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have updated to asp.net mvc3 from Microsoft site, but running it in vs2010 have errors:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an
>   assembly manifest.

Then I added `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` in solution referece, still have problem. Using `gacutil /i Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` cannot work. So how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have seen the article for "MVC3 Deployment Dependency Problems", this did not wrok for me, I cannot run mvc3 web page in vs2010 web server

Comment: Just a stupid question but is the Microsoft.Web.Infrastrcture dll in the bin folder of your web application? Id this is a hosting provider I am sure they have a limited amount of libs in the GAC

Answer (score 0):

May you try to update your environment using Microsoft Web Platform Installer.
To run asp.net mvc3, you need also to install SP1 of VS10, but you can install all you need from the Web Platform Installer.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx